# Convert String to Time Python

Tags: python

I have a time String like this：

```
07/01/2015-14:31:58.520
```

I use this command line to convert it:

```
import time
timeStr = "07/01/2015-14:31:58.520"
time.strptime(timeStr,'%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But this returns:

> ValueError: time data '07/01/2015-14:31:58.520' does not match format
>   '%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:S.%f'

My python version is 2.7.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%y` denotes a 2 digit year, but your string has a 4 digit year.  Use `%Y` (capital Y) to denote a 4 digit year.  See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) for more information.

```
time.strptime(timeStr, '%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Note that [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) may be more useful, as it will return a full `datetime` object rather than a tuple.  [The format syntax is essentially the same](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

It should have been capital **Y** for year (%Y in place of %y)

```
time.strptime(timeStr,'%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a `datetime` object, use `python-dateutil`

To install

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Then

```
t = "07/01/2015-14:31:58.520"
from dateutil import  parser
>>>parser.parse(t)
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 1, 14, 31, 58, 520000)

tim = parser.parse(t)
>>>str(tim.date())
'2015-07-01'
```

All operations to `datetime` objects is possible.

Comment: Is this from another third party library？

Comment: sorry i didnt metion it. `pip install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use %Y instead of %y

```
time.strptime(timeStr,'%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

the time.strptime syntax `%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S.%f` is incorrect, it should be

> "%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f"

where the only difference is that `%y` has become `%Y`. The reason is because from  [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)  `%y` is without century number ( [00,99] ), whereas `%Y` is with century number, which is the syntax you use with "2015"

Tested and functinal in python 2.7.5 and 3.4.1

Edit: Zero answers when I started typing this, 6 answers by time of post, sorry about that!

Edit #2: datetime.strptime functions similarly, so if you want to use that as well, you can!